# Powershell Remoting Profiles

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

How do I use a function in my profile on the remote machine when using `Enter-PSSession` on my local machine to open a remote PowerShell session.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. When starting a remote interactive session with enter-pssession, a remote profile is loaded. Additionally, only the machine-level profile in $pshome is loaded. If you want remote functions available you'll have to initialize them in the startup script of the remote session configuration. Have a look at get/set-pssessionconfiguration on the remote server.

Comment: Did something change in the way these things are handled? I'm with powershell 5.1 and I created a profile.ps1 in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ just to set an alias, which is working when using the shell locally. But when connecting to that machine using Enter-PSSession, the alias is not working...

Comment: @Alex Perhaps you may need to restart the WinRM service on the server end? A reboot should do it, but if this is a little heavyweight then "restart-service winrm" should work. Or, things may have changed as you say...

Answer (score 32):

By JonZ and x0n:

> When you use pssessions with the default session configurations, no profile scripts run.
>
> When starting a remote interactive session with `Enter-PSSession`, a remote profile is loaded. Additionally, only the machine-level profile in `$pshome` is loaded.

If you want a session to be preconfigured (to load custom functions, snap-ins, modules, etc.), add a profile script to a new **sessionconfiguration** (for initialize them in the startup script of the remote session configuration).

The [Register-PSSessionConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819496.aspx) cmdlet creates and registers a new session configuration on the local computer. Use [Get-PSSessionConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819447.aspx) to view existing session configurations. Both Get-PSSessionConfiguration and Register-PSSessionConfiguration require elevated rights (start PowerShell with the “Run as Administrator” option).

In the target computer, where `profile.ps1` contains all your functions:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name WithProfile -StartupScript $PsHome\Profile.ps1
```

To use this preconfigured session you would type, from the local computer:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -ConfigurationName WithProfile
```

or

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -ConfigurationName WithProfile -Credential youradminuser@yourtargetdomain
```

(where `$computername` is the hostname of the remote server where you registered the pssessionconfiguration).

A good source on PowerShell remoting is the [Administrator's Guide to Powershell Remoting](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7257.aspx).

**References:**
[Powershell Remoting: Use Functions loaded in Powershell remote Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860944/powershell-remoting-use-functions-loaded-in-powershell-remote-profile)
http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/update-creating-a-profile-for-a-remote-session/

**Understanding and Using PowerShell Profiles**
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/04/understanding-and-using-powershell-profiles.aspx

**About_Profiles (Microsoft Docs)**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles

The six different Windows PowerShell profile paths and use

*Current User, Current Host - console*
$Home[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1

*Current User, All Hosts*
$Home[My ]Documents\Profile.ps1

*All Users, Current Host - console*
$PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

*All Users, All Hosts*
$PsHome\Profile.ps1

*Current user, Current Host - ISE*
$Home[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1

*All users, Current Host - ISE*
$PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1

**Windows PowerShell Profiles**
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488%28VS.85%29.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)

*This profile applies to all users and all shells.*
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1

*This profile applies to all users, but only to the Microsoft.PowerShell shell.*
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

*This profile applies only to the current user, but affects all shells.*
%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

*This profile applies only to the current user and the Microsoft.PowerShell shell.*
%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

**PowerShell Core Profiles**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles

*This profile applies to all users and all hosts.*
$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\6\profile.ps1

*This profile applies to all users, but only to the current host.*
$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\6\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

*This profile applies only to the current user, but affects all hosts.*
$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1

*This profile applies only to the current user and the Microsoft.PowerShell shell.*
$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Comment: "Additionally, only the machine-level profile in $pshome is loaded." Has this changed at some point? With Windows 8.1 and WIndoes Server 2012, Enter-PSSession is not running any Powershell profiles on the target machine.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker - I'm seeing this too. With a Win 2008 R2 / PS 3.0 server.

Comment: If you don't want to depend on a specific windows version or language, use: `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')`

Answer (score 7):

Jason,
In my case, I wanted to have my Powershell Profile follow me when I remoted into another computer.

I have created a wrapper function Remote that takes a computername, creates a session, loads your profile into the session, and uses enter-pssession.

Here is the code below:

```
function Remote($computername){
if(!$Global:credential){
$Global:credential =  Get-Credential
}
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -Credential $credential
Invoke-Command -FilePath $profile -Session $session
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
}
```

You could modify the Invoke-Command -FilePath parameter to take any file of your liking.

Comment: This works, but PowerShell has a few bugs that stop it from working well.  First, there's no way to wait on "Enter-PSSession -Session", which mean as soon as you call this statement you have spawed a new process in the same window with no wait to spinlock in the script until a users types exit.  Invoke-command -session, runs in parallel not in serial...so its a race condition..  Better to do this with the other method and never use "New-Session"... If microsoft had a mode that ensured that each invoke command was serially executed...

Comment: @pico, This isn't intended for use in a script. It should Mimic using ssh on a linux host.

Also, Invoke-Command runs synchronously, and is not a Race Condition. 
Notice I'm using New-Session only one time, and then use Invoke and Enter on the same object. You need multiple sessions to get concurrency. 
j.ps1 Contents:
`$id = (New-Guid).Guid; $sleep = Get-Random -Min 1 -Max 10;  "Job $id sleep-time: $sleep"`
`0..5 | % {"$id : $_";sleep $sleep}`

Test Script
`$session = New-PSSession;`
`0..10  | %{ Invoke-Command -FilePath "j.ps1" -Session $session}`

Results indicate serial.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this

http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/creating-a-profile-for-a-remote-session/

its a work around for creating a remote profile.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to use a profile on a remote session:

1. Copy the chosen profile to the remote server(s) in your documents folder. For example:

`Copy-Item -Path $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts -Destination \\computername\C$\Users\MyAccountName\Documents`

2. Enter the PSSession

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ComputerName`

3. Dot source your profile

`. .\Profile.ps1`

Drawbacks of this solution:

- you must copy once your profile to all the computers where you want to have a profile
- you must dot source the profile every time you enter a PSSession

Advantages of this solution:

- There is no need of function and you just enter a PSSession like you always do
- You do not alter all users' profile by changing the default session configuration

(Thanks to [Jeffery Hicks for the tip about the dot sourcing](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/6449/thinking-outside-the-box-with-another-powershell-prompt))