# Powershell Remoting: Use Functions loaded in Powershell remote Profile?

Tags: powershell, profile, powershell-remoting

Do i get it right that when i have a Profile on a RemoteServer which loads some functions, these functions should be available in a Remote PSSession?

My tests weren't successfull, is there a special trick to get this working?

I want to refer to Folder on a network share to have all Functions on a single source available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use pssessions with the default session configurations, no profile scripts run.  If you want a session to be preconfigured (to load custom functions, snap-ins, modules ...), add a profile script to a new **sessionconfiguration**. The [Register-PSSessionConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819496.aspx) cmdlet creates and registers a new session configuration on the local computer. Use [Get-PSSessionConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819447.aspx) to view existing session configurations. Both Get-PSSessionConfiguration and Register-PSSessionConfiguration require elevated rights (start PowerShell with the “Run as Administrator” option).

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name WithProfile -StartupScript $PsHome\Profile.ps1
```

To use this preconfigured session you would type:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -ConfigurationName WithProfile
```

(where $computername is the hostname of RemoteServer where you registered the pssessionconfiguration).

A good source on powershell remoting is the [Administrator's Guide to Powershell Remoting](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7257.aspx).

Comment: When starting a remote interactive session with enter-pssession, a remote profile is loaded. Additionally, only the machine-level profile in $pshome is loaded. If you want remote functions available you'll have to initialize them in the startup script of the remote session configuration. Have a look at get/set-pssessionconfiguration on the remote server. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985127/206730

Comment: what took me awhile to realize is that you need to do 'register/set-pssessionconfiguration' on the remote machine, not the local one