# Powershell: How to identify if a script block is executing locally or within a remote session

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Let's assume I have the following script block

```
$scriptBlock={
   $isRemote=.....
}
```

If I do

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

I expect $isRemote to be false.

If I do

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "EXAMPLE" -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

I expect $isRemote to be true.

How can I populate the `$isRemote`. I suppose the same reasoning will apply when executing within a remote session.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer
This is from a local `Get-Host`

```
Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 4.0
InstanceId       : 14cd6e79-2839-4297-8c7e-ac003f9715a2
UI               :     System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

his is from a remote `Get-Host`

```
PSComputerName   : meculab13001.global.sdl.corp
RunspaceId       : 34fca087-793c-4c87-bab8-8be5d61d06e5
Name             : ServerRemoteHost
Version          : 1.0.0.0
InstanceId       : 3fcb51c2-30c1-49af-8898-afbd5574b20b
UI               :    System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : 
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

I recognize two differences
In a remote execution context, `PSComputerName` is defined
In a remote execution context, `Name` is `ServerRemoteHost` instead of `Windows PowerShell ISE Host`

Answer (score 0):

`PCComputerName` is added because of the remote invocation. I settled to the following

```
if((Get-Host).Name -eq "ServerRemoteHost") {
    $DebugPreference=$Using:DebugPreference
    $VerbosePreference=$Using:VerbosePreference
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394196/how-to-check-if-a-powershell-script-is-running-remotely) this looks better

```
if($PSSenderInfo) {
    $DebugPreference=$Using:DebugPreference
    $VerbosePreference=$Using:VerbosePreference
}
```