# Unable to activate a conda virtual environment on a remote computer on the same network in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

I am using Windows Powershell to remote into another computer on the same network by using the following command:

```
C:\Users\User1>powershell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    

PS C:\Users\User1> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName REMOTECOMPUTER1
```

After that, I want to activate a conda virtual environment by doing the following:

```
[REMOTECOMPUTER1]: PS C:\Users\User1\Documents> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\conda activate User1_Env
```

However, the command above doesn't seem to do anything. The returned prompt doesn't have the virtual environment name in the front.

```
[REMOTECOMPUTER1]: PS C:\Users\User1\Documents>
```

To test if the virtual env has been activated, I run a simple python script that imports a package that is installed in the virtual env (but not in the base env), I get an error message saying there is no such module, suggesting that the virtual env has not been activated.

Any suggestions and pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you need to register a remote configuration on the remote server, and specify that configuration in your `Enter-PSSession` call.

The `-StartupScript` in the remote configuration should point to the file that contains your profile settings (with the conda initialize block) on the remote machine. For example this can be `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WinwdowsPowershell\profile.ps1` (but this might differ on your machine).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14997258/1256347) goes into detail about configuring the `PSSessionConfiguration`.